# When passing state values to variant, the duration won't change

Tags: framer-motion

The children of the parent component have to speed up their x animation. This is done by using useCycle when the parent is hovered, which changes the child variants. This works ok and the children speed up when the parent is hovered.

The problem is that when the parent is hovered the animation starts from the beginning and the children start from their initial x position making the animation look forced and unnatural.

To fix this I created an event listener in the children with useMotionValueEvent to watch for animationCancel. This indicates when the variant has been cycled by the parent. Inside of the listener I check if the child is in view with useInView and if it is, I set the state to the current x position of the variable and this is assigned to the variant:

```
import { motion, useCycle } from "framer-motion";
import SVGReactRouter from "../../svgs/SVGReactRouter";



const Parent = ({
  xAnimation,
  cycleAnimation,
}) => {
  const [xAnimation, cycleAnimation] = useCycle("cycleX", "cycleXFast");


  return (
    <div>
      <motion.div
        onMouseLeave={() => cycleAnimation(0)}
        onMouseEnter={() => cycleAnimation(1)}
        
      >
        <div>
          <div>
            <SVGReactRouter xAnimation={xAnimation} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </motion.div>
    </div>
  );
};


import {  useRef, useState } from "react";
import {
  motion,
  Variants,
  useTransform,
  useMotionValue,
  useMotionTemplate,
  useInView,
  useMotionValueEvent,
} from "framer-motion";
import { SVGPropsType } from "./SVGTypeScript";

const SVGReactRouter = ({ xAnimation }) => {
  const [keyframes, setKeyframes] = useState([0, 320]);
  const x = useMotionValue(0);
  const ref = useRef<SVGSVGElement>(null);
  const isInView = useInView(ref);


  useMotionValueEvent(x, "animationCancel", () => {
    if (isInView) {
      setKeyframes([x.get(), 320 - x.get()]);
    } else {
      setKeyframes([0, 320]);
    }
  });

  const svgVariant: Variants = {
    cycleX: {
      x: keyframes,
      transition: { duration: 5, repeat: Infinity, delay: 3, repeatDelay: 1.1 },
    },
    cycleXFast: {
      x: keyframes,
      transition: {
        duration: 3,
        repeat: Infinity,
        delay: 1.5,
        repeatDelay: 0.5,
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <motion.svg
      ref={ref}
      style={{x}}
      variants={svgVariant}
      animate={xAnimation}
      width="80px"
      height="90px"
      viewBox="0 -58 256 256"
      version="1.1"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid"
      stroke="white"
      strokeWidth="5"
    >
      <g>
        <path
          stroke="white"
          strokeWidth="5"
          d="M78.0659341,92.5875806 C90.8837956,92.5875806 101.274726,82.1966508 101.274726,69.3787894 C101.274726,56.5609279 90.8837956,46.1699982 78.0659341,46.1699982 C65.2480726,46.1699982 54.8571429,56.5609279 54.8571429,69.3787894 C54.8571429,82.1966508 65.2480726,92.5875806 78.0659341,92.5875806 Z M23.2087913,139.005163 C36.0266526,139.005163 46.4175825,128.614233 46.4175825,115.796372 C46.4175825,102.97851 36.0266526,92.5875806 23.2087913,92.5875806 C10.3909298,92.5875806 0,102.97851 0,115.796372 C0,128.614233 10.3909298,139.005163 23.2087913,139.005163 Z M232.791209,139.005163 C245.60907,139.005163 256,128.614233 256,115.796372 C256,102.97851 245.60907,92.5875806 232.791209,92.5875806 C219.973347,92.5875806 209.582418,102.97851 209.582418,115.796372 C209.582418,128.614233 219.973347,139.005163 232.791209,139.005163 Z"
          fill="#61030e"
        ></path>
        <path
          d="M156.565464,70.3568084 C155.823426,62.6028163 155.445577,56.1490255 149.505494,51.6131676 C141.982638,45.8687002 133.461166,49.5960243 122.964463,45.8072968 C112.650326,43.3121427 105,34.1545727 105,23.2394367 C105,10.4046502 115.577888,0 128.626373,0 C138.29063,0 146.599638,5.70747659 150.259573,13.8825477 C155.861013,24.5221258 152.220489,35.3500418 159.258242,40.8041273 C167.591489,47.2621895 178.826167,42.5329154 191.362109,48.6517412 C195.390112,50.5026944 198.799584,53.4384578 201.202056,57.0769224 C203.604528,60.7153869 205,65.0565524 205,69.7183101 C205,80.633446 197.349674,89.7910161 187.035538,92.2861702 C176.538834,96.0748977 168.017363,92.3475736 160.494506,98.092041 C152.03503,104.551712 156.563892,115.358642 149.669352,126.774447 C145.756163,134.291567 137.802119,139.43662 128.626373,139.43662 C115.577888,139.43662 105,129.03197 105,116.197184 C105,106.873668 110.581887,98.832521 118.637891,95.1306146 C131.173833,89.0117889 142.408511,93.7410629 150.741758,87.2830007 C155.549106,83.5574243 156.565464,77.8102648 156.565464,70.3568084 Z"
          fill="#af0216"
        ></path>
      </g>
    </motion.svg>
  );
};

export default SVGReactRouter;
```

But after doing this, now the duration of the variant stays at cycleX even though this updates the position correctly with the keyframe state. Why is this state injection messing with the variant duration?